# Decrease and conquer algorithm with recursion: get unique number of ordered list

Tags: python, algorithm

EDIT: The idea is to use a decrease and conquer algorithm that uses recursion and not complex functions of Python. All possible arrays used are always ordered by value.

Function: `search_index_unique_number(v,i,j)`

For example with:

```
v1 = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8]
v2 = [10,10,17,17,18,18,19,19,21,21,23]
v3 = [1,3,3,5,5,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10]
```

Way to execute it:

```
pos = search_index_unique_number(v1,0,len(v1))
print(pos, v[pos]) #with v1 it should show: 4 3
```

First version (it doesn't work well):

```
def search_index_unique_number(v,i,j):
    if len(v) == 1:
        return v[0]
    if len(v) == 0:
        return None
    v = v[i:j]
    if len(v) == 2:
        if(v[0] == v[1]):
            return None
        else:
            return v
    else:
        h = len(v)//2
        return search_index_unique_number(v, 0, h),  search_index_unique_number(v, h, len(v))
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @alexmcf Sorry, now I edit it. The question is how to solve it, i will add now a first version that doesn't work. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Alfe I have just added a piece of code of my try. It doesn't work properly but it shows what is my idea.

Comment: Please explain "doesnt work very well".  What does it do ?

Comment: I don't see where you are explaining what the function should do. Are you asking for it to return the number(s) that are not repeated in the provided list? So for `v1` it returns 3, for `v2` it returns 23 and for `v3` it returns 1. What has an ordered list got to do with it?

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? What do the `i` and `j` arguments mean? Are they `start`/`stop` arguments, so you're effectively searching `v[i:j]`? Is "unique" supposed to mean the first element that isn't the same as either of its neighbors, or the first element in `v[i:j]` that doesn't appear anywhere else in the list, or the first element in `v[i:j]` that doesn't appear anywhere else in `v[i:j]`, or…?

Comment: @abarnert The idea is that in that ordered list there is only one number that is not repeated. The function has to use recursion, so i and j are the indexes used of v vector.

Comment: @paul-rooney The idea is that the function has to return the index of the vector that is not repeated.

Comment: Are the values guaranteed to be in sorted order, as in your three examples?

Comment: @abarnert Yes, all vector values will be in sorted order.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the important information, don't just leave it in comments. Read [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some guidance on what to include in a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a count of all elements with a Counter dict, then get the first element that only appears once from the list by doing a lookup in the dict

```
from collections import Counter
cn = Counter(v1)
print(next((i,ele) for i,ele in enumerate(v1) if cn[ele] == 1 ))
(4, 3)
```

If you cannot use a lib, make your own counter dict:

```
cn = {}
for ele in v1:
    cn.setdefault(ele, 0) 
    cn[ele] += 1

print(next((i,ele) for i,ele in enumerate(v1) if cn[ele] == 1))
```

In a function:

```
def search_index_unique_number(l,start, end):
    cn = {}
    for ele in l[start:end]:
        cn.setdefault(ele, 0)
        cn[ele] += 1
    return next(((i,ele) for i,ele in enumerate(v1) if cn[ele] == 1),"No unique element")

 print(search_index_unique_number(v1,0,len(v1)))
 (4, 3)
```

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited it with more info. The idea is to solve the algorithm without other libraries. I have just added a first version of mine that doesn't work properly.

Comment: It works, the use of enumerate or setdefault is a bit more complex, the idea is not using these tools, but it totally works. But this is not a decrease and conquer algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a recursive divide-and-conquer solution to this, either start at the top and think about what it means to divide the list in half, or start at the bottom and think about what it means to concatenate two lists.

Assuming that the inputs are guaranteed to be in sorted order, and there's guaranteed to be at most 1 unique value, as you said in the comments, this is pretty easy.

Starting at the bottom:

- Any 1-element list has a unique value. So, if `j==i+1`, then `v[i]` is unique.
- Concatenating a list with a unique value to another list preserves the unique value unless it's at the edge, and the same element is repeated at the edge of the other list.

  - So if `v[i:j]` has a unique value at `x`, then `v[i:k]` has a unique value at `x` iff `x<j-1 or j==k or v[x] != v[x+1]`.
  - And likewise for concatenating in the other direction, if it's the right one that has a unique value.
  - And if both halves have unique values, you need to do both tests.
  - While if neither half has a unique value, the concatenated list can't have a unique value.

I'll leave it up to you to turn that pseudocode into a complete implementation, but other than making sure to avoid fencepost errors (e.g., decide how to handle an empty list) there's nothing complicated there.

Extending this to handle cases where they may be more than 1 unique value is easy if you return *all* the unique values. Just loop over each unique value returned by the recursive calls and do the same logic to filter them out. (You can optimize that a bit by only checking the last/first one, of course.)

Extending this to handle non-sorted inputs, however, is not trivial to do without blowing up the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(v1[1:], v1, [None]+v1)):
  if a != b != c:
    print i, b
```

or even:

```
for i in range(1, len(v1)-1):
  if v1[i-1] != v1[i] != v1[i+1]:
    print i, v1[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with any iterable:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def unique_numbers_index(iterable, start, end):
    numbers_with_index = {}
    duplicated = []

    # Create list of numbers (with index) and list of duplicated numbers
    for idx, value in enumerate(iterable[start:end]):
        if value in numbers_with_index.keys():
            duplicated.append(value)
        numbers_with_index[value] = idx

    # Remove duplicated numbers
    [numbers_with_index.pop(key) for key in duplicated]

    # Return a tuple with index of unique numbers
    return tuple(numbers_with_index.values())
```

Example:

```
v1 = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8]
v2 = [10,10,17,17,18,18,19,19,21,21,23]
v3 = [1,3,3,5,5,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10]

print 'v1: {}'.format(v1)
print 'unique: {}'.format([v1[idx] for idx in unique_numbers_index(v1, 0, len(v1))])

print 'v2: {}'.format(v2)
print 'unique: {}'.format([v2[idx] for idx in unique_numbers_index(v2, 0, len(v2))])

print 'v3: {}'.format(v3)
print 'unique: {}'.format([v3[idx] for idx in unique_numbers_index(v3, 0, len(v3))])
```

Output:

```
v1: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]
unique: [3]
v2: [10, 10, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 21, 23]
unique: [23]
v3: [1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]
unique: [1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I say at EDIT: "The idea is to use a decrease and conquer algorithm that uses recursion and not complex functions of Python".

Answer (score 0):

The focus of this answer is to returns the values matching the `i` repetitions within the input list `v1` using minimal **lines** of code.

#### Solution

```
# get values
vals = lambda v,i : [val for val in set(v) if v.count(val) == i]

# EDIT: to obtain the indices...
indices = lambda matched_vals, v: [[i for i, x in enumerate(v) if x == val] for val in matched_vals]
```

#### Test

```
v1 = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8]
vals(v1, 1) # get a list of all unique values in v1
[3]
vals(v1, 2) # get a list of all values that have a count of 2 in v1
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

#### Explanation

```
# create a set of the unique items in v1
set_vals = set(v1) # which gives {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

# check the count of each value in the set == 1
values = [val for val in set_val if v1.count(val) == 1 ]
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the idea is to do it without any complex library, only with the elements I used in my example.

Comment: we can't use a test, that is not using a decrease and conquer algorithm

Comment: @RyanHaining it wasn't too clear what he was actually intending with this question... This answer just focuses on returning the list items matching the count criteria in one line